# Como utilizar if/else dentro de uma função?

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando criar uma função simples, pra escrever o título de acordo com a seleção de sexo no formulário, mas devo estar fazendo algo errado:

```
$sexo = empty($_POST['sexo']) ? "[sexo]" : $_POST['sexo'];

function mudasexo($sexo) {

    if ($sexo == "masculino") {
            echo "O senhor";
        }
    else {
        echo "A senhora";
    }
}
```

Daí queria usar esta função dentro de textos em HTML com: `<?php mudasexo() ?>` mas não tá funcionando. Não acusa nenhum erro quando *debugo*, mas a página nem abre.

Comment: No meu teste apareceu "A Senhora"

Comment: O problema parece não ser a função, se chamar ela como está ai funciona.

Comment: @rray Pode ser porque este arquivo onde coloquei a função é incluído via include num arquivo, que depois é incluído em outro? Agora olhando direito o debug aqui achei este erro PHP `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare mudasexo() (previously declared in arq1.php:90) in arq1.php on line 98`...

Comment: É só apagar a versão da função que está no lugar errado.

Comment: Isso @rray!
@gustavox, habilite o *error reporting*

Comment: Não, a função tá declarada só uma vez. É que é assim, quando o form roda ele chama um arquivo (saida.php, que é html/php), e no fim deste arquivo tem um include que chama outro arquivo (saida2php - que tbm é um arquivo html/php), sendo que este que chama outro só de script (e neste é que está a função, e este script só atua no arquivo saida2php). @rray

Comment: Aí o arquivo saida.php (o primeiro) abre só até a metade, quando é pra começar o 2 não abre mais... Só se retiro a função...

Comment: Achei que tinha a ver quando o if/else, mas acho que tem a ver com o jeito to usando include e tal... valeu ae de qualquer forma à todos que ajudaram... Abraços.

Comment: vc chama por include ou include_once ?

Comment: Ah @rray, por include (mas mudei pra include_once agora hehe), mas quando li seu comentário fui olhar e eu tava chamando o arquivo do script nas duas páginas (saida e saida2)... chamando só no primeiro funcionou! valeu^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu faria diferente, vejo vários erros conceituais na função, mas o único problema que impede o funcionamento é a chamada da função no HTML, a função espera um parâmetro, você não está passando nenhum argumento. Acho que isto é seu argumento:

```
<?php mudasexo(empty($_POST['sexo']) ? "[sexo]" : $_POST['sexo']) ?>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/Options.php).

Mesmo com o problema, se não está aparecendo nada então há problemas em outras partes do código.

---

Conforme os comentários, o problema real era na declaração da função mas ainda vale repensar nela.

Comment: Então, o problema acho que é porque este arquivo onde coloquei a função é incluído via include num arquivo, que depois é incluído em outro... agora olhando direito o debug aqui achei este erro `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare mudasexo() (previously declared in arq1.php:90) in arq1.php on line 98`...

Comment: Sim, neste seu caso faltou passar o parametro da função mudasexo($cod)

Comment: Então, mas a questão é que mesmo que eu não chame a função, que só coloque ela no arquivo de script, já dá o problema. Se tiro a função, fica normal...@AndréBaill

Comment: Achei que tinha a ver com o if/else, mas acho que tem a ver com o jeito to usando include e tal... valeu ae de qualquer forma à todos que ajudaram...

Comment: O problema é que tava chamando o arquivo do script duas vezes... Valeu de novo à todos.

Comment: O problema de não estar abrindo era com o `include` do script sendo chamado duas vezes mesmo, mas também tinha esse porém de não estar passando o argumento, então marquei sua resposta como aceita (mas usei apenas `mudasexo($sexo)` porque já tinha a variável declarada). Btw, poderia falar algo sobre os erros conceituais e/ou fazer um exemplo de que como vc faria?

Comment: A função deveria retornar um valor ao invés de imprimir algo, assim separa a tarefa de selecionar o que imprimir com a de imprimir. Ela trata o `masculino` como uma coisa e todo o resto como outra. Você não está comparando algo que só pode ter dois estados. O nome da função é esquisito, não só pela expressão usada, mas você não está mudando o sexo de nada dentro dela. E por aí vai...

Comment: kkkk é, o nome ficou esquisito mesmo :-)  O `masculino` é o value de um `select`, que só tem duas opções mesmo, mas quando fiz um `elseif` com  `$sexo == "feminino"` acabei achando redundante e deixei só o `else` mesmo... Mas então pelo que vc disse o certo seria fazer algo como `if ($sexo == "masculino")` { return true;}` e daí embaixo um outro if `if ($sexo == true) { echo...}`?

Comment: Aí é que tá, você está confiando que a página que é algo que você não tem controle vai mandar o dado certinho. Isso é um erro. Se você retornar `true` vai imprimir `true` que não é o que você quer. E nunca coloque em um `if` um `$variavel == true`, isto sim é redundante.

Comment: Mas na declaração da variável eu to usando o `empty`, que no caso faz essa verificação do dado... não faz diferença? No caso então seria melhor fazer o `elseif` pra feminino e um `else` com return `false`? Ou seria melhor... fazer outra pergunta? :)

Comment: Que verifica só se está vazia, mais nada. Pode vir outra coisa. E pior, você verifica e cria um terceiro estado, que você afirma que não existe. Seu código garante que existe.

Comment: aff agora fiquei com medo. :-) Vou pensar melhor e depois ver se criou outra pergunta mais específica. Valeu por enquanto!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
function mudarSexo($sexo){

    switch($sexo){
        default: 
            $mudanca = 'Sexo não selecionado';
            break;

        case 'masculino':
            $mudanca = 'Senhor';
            break;

        case 'feminino':
            $mudanca = 'Senhora';
            break;      
    }

    return $mudanca;
}

echo mudarSexo("masculino"); // Imprime -> Senhor
echo mudarSexo("feminino"); // Imprime -> Senhora
echo mudarSexo(""); // Imprime -> Sexo não selecionado
```